# State Space and circuit simulator

Tags: graph, theory, simulator, circuit

As far as I know there is no state-space based general purpose circuit simulator around. Though there are certain algorithm to figure out how to find state-spaces (unique?) in a circuit (represented by graphs). Has anyone tried writing a program to simulate some basic circuit elements?

[ref] 1. Sheshu and Reed, Electrical networks and graph theory.
[ref] 2. H Narayanan, Submodular Functions and Electrical Networks ( http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~hn )

Answer (score 2):

Old post..

Once you have derived the state-space representation of your electrical circuit, you can use any suitable ODE solver to run the time-domain simulation.

The harder part is the derivation of the state-space equations from a netlist via MNA or a tree approach.

See
ANALOG CIRCUIT SIMULATION BY STATE VARIABLE METHOD by Rodica VOICULESCU1 and Mihai IORDACHE

Answer (score 0):

Commercial simulators along these lines are PLECS, PSIM, Simplis, SimPowerSystems etc.

The classic book 'Computer-aided Analysis of Electronic Circuits: Algorithms and Computational Techniques' by Leon O. Chua and Pen-Min Lin contains a description of state-space based simulators. I found the book sufficiently 
detailed to successfully write a simulator for piece-wise linear networks with ideal switches.

When you are primarily interested in non-linear networks (semiconductors, nonlinear inductors and capacitors, etc.) an MNA-based SPICE-like
approach is probably a much better idea. The book also contains 
these basic algorithms (in unparalleled depth), but has nothing 
on device modeling.